# How to capture HTTP headers when invoking php-cgi as a subprocess?

Tags: php, qt, batch-file, http-headers, cgi

I'm trying to capture HTTP headers in subprocess of my application that acts as a web server. When i'm invoking php-cgi.exe from command line, HTTP headers are printed to STDOUT, but when I'm trying to catch process's output in QProcess, it returns only HTML.

C++ code:

```
QProcess php_process;
php_process.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
php_process.start( "cgi_get.bat" );
php_process.waitForFinished();
QString php_response(php_process.readAll());
```

cgi_get.bat:

```
@echo off
set REDIRECT_STATUS=CGI
set SCRIPT_FILENAME=index.php

C:\application\php-cgi.exe  -f C:\application\app\webroot\index.php
```

STDOUT after calling cgi_get.bat from command line:

```
Status: 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.13
Set-Cookie: CAKEPHP=fdo35gsnp9hde6a7sufkkb7hj3; expires=Thu, 03-Apr-2014 19:46:06 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Content-Length: 24844
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> ... blah blah blah
```

php_response contents after running this c++ code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />        <title> blah blah blah
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `php-cgi.exe` behaves correctly, then your assertion that the headers are output to `stdout` is demonstrably incorrect. They are when you run it in a console, from the command line, but obviously they aren't when you run it without a console, from `QProcess`.

To ensure that your use of `QProcess` is correct, run the following batch file instead:

```
echo Headers >&2
```

As long as the you see that line, it means that your code is OK, and `php-cgi.exe` is misbehaving.

It almost seems that the server process suppresses header output if it's not attached to a terminal/console. You'd need to check the documentation of `php-cgi.exe` to figure out how to force it to output the headers.

Comment: @kosto I don't know what you mean, but what I wrote above is true. Somehow the `php-cgi` executable is not outputting the headers. There's nothing you can do about it in your code. There's of course a possibility that `QProcess` is somehow broken.

Comment: Very strange, it started to work, after I cleaned and rebuilt my QT project.